# Understanding powershell regular expression

Tags: regex, powershell

Morning

on my VM i have IIS installed and some test websites setup called

```
Test1.mav359.co.uk
Test2.mav359.co.uk
Test3.mav359.co.uk
```

My goal is to dynamically create a hostfile for the web developers and their local sites, another user helped me with the following piece of code

```
 $Array = Get-IISSite | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.ID -gt 1) {
        '{1}    {0}' -f ($_.Name -replace '^(\w+\d+)', '$1-local'),
                        $(if ($_.Name -like '*mav359*') { $IP1 } else { $IP2 })
    }

}
```

This works great, exactly what i need and outputs the following

```
10.0.0.1    Test1-local.mav359.co.uk
10.0.0.1    test2-local.mav359.co.uk
10.0.0.1    test3-local.mav359.co.uk
```

Pefect but....

i dont understand how this part of the code works

```
'^(\w+\d+)',
```

i think \w+ = to the text of test & the \d+ = to the digit eg.1 so \test+\1+

what i dont understand.... its just looking at the test1 part of the full website name, how does it know to insert the -local before the .mav359.co.uk

im unsure how the code works to define the part of the name its looking at

sorry for teh stupid question but i want to know why it works not just that it does

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex `^(\w+\d+)` simply captures the part from the beginning of the string that starts with word-characters and ends with one or more digits.

In your examples this would be `Test1`, `test2` and `test3`.

The replacement part then replaces that captured part with itself (`$1`) followed by `-local`

In detail:

```
^             Assert position at the beginning of the string
(             Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \w         Match a single character that is a “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, connector punctuation)
      +       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \d         Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script)
      +       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```